# Use PHP templating instead of Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am learning Symfony2 with Twig, but I also want to know how to write templates in PHP. I have two templates:

```
New message from {{ name }}
Sent from courot.com/contact
IP: {{ ip }}

{{ message|raw }}
```

and

```
{% for label, flashes in app.session.flashbag.all %}
    {% for flash in flashes %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ label }}">
            {{ flash }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am wondering how these would be converted to PHP templates.

Comment: Check docs:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages and this one: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Comment: Is this homework? If you need to translate TWIG to PHP, you can read [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html)

Comment: i guess you need to do a bit of reading on your own if this will be relevant for a test...not every teacher allows stack overflow as a reference while doing your test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added `php` to the templating config in your `config.yml` file:

```
framework:
    templating: { engines: ['twig', 'php'] }
```

Then rewrite that code in PHP and give your template a `.php` extension:

```
New message from <?php echo $view->escape($name) ?>
Sent from courot.com/contact
IP: <?php echo $view->escape($ip) ?>

<?php echo $message ?>
```

and:

```
<?php foreach ($app->getSession()->getFlashbag()->all() as $label => $flashes): ?>
    <?php foreach ($flashes as $flash): ?>
      <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $view->escape($label) ?>">
          <?php echo $view->escape($flash) ?>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note the frequent use of `$view->escape`. That is necessary since PHP does not have automatic output escaping like Twig does. The only variable that doesn't need escaping is `message` which was piped into the `raw` filter in the Twig version.

Comment: <?php foreach ($flash in $flashes): ?> getting error on this

Comment: @AleksandarGunnerDimovski My bad. I used Javascript-like syntax. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to configure your project to use PHP templates. Check `app/config/config.yml` whether you have this parameter already set like this:

```
framework:
    templating: { engines: ['twig', 'php'] }
```

Now you have to use the `.php:` extension on your templates and render them in your controller like this:

```
public function indexAction() {
    return $this->render('VendorBundlenameBundle:Index:index.html.php', array(
            'ip' => $ip,
            'message' => $message
    ));
}
```

Finally in your templates simply use the variable names you have passed, like:

```
IP: <?php print $ip; ?>
Messsage: <?php htmlspecialchars($message); ?>
```